# Discord.py check for JSON updates

Tags: python, json, python-requests, discord.py

I have this really messy code (first thing I do in Python) that IMO should work but it dosn't.

```
import os
import discord
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests

purl = "https://28chan.org/board/p/threads.json"
presponse = requests.get(url=purl)
pdata = presponse.json()
threadp = pdata

url = "https://28chan.org/board/p/threads.json"

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
        channel = client.get_channel(795037657108447302)
        try:
                while True:
                        response = requests.get(url=url)
                        data = response.json()
                        print (data[0]['threads'][0]['last_modified'])
                        huh = data[0]['threads'][0]['last_modified']
                        if huh > threadp:
                                threadp = huh
                        await channel.send(threadp)
                time.sleep(20)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pass

client.run(TOKEN)
```

When I execute it it works the first time the loop runs then the second time it says:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 37, in on_ready
    if huh > threadp:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'threadp' referenced before assignment
```

why is that? I know its something about threadp but what is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because inside the `on_ready()` function, `threadp` is a local variable. Just add this to the function and it should work:

```py
global threadp
```

---

So, your even would look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(795037657108447302)
    try:
        while True:
            response = requests.get(url=url)
            data = response.json()
            print (data[0]['threads'][0]['last_modified'])
            huh = data[0]['threads'][0]['last_modified']
            global threadp  # Telling the function to use the global variable
            if huh > threadp:
                threadp = huh
            await channel.send(threadp)
        time.sleep(20)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Comment: @test no prob! Please mark this as the solution if it helped.